# Is there an R function for checking if a value is a legal index in a vector or list?

Tags: r, indexing

There are several ways to index i R e.g. by selecting using positive integers, by excluding using negative integers, by selecting using logicals/conditions, by selecting using names (character-vectors) in a named vector or list, and probably a lot of other ways than that.
What I want is a function taking two inputs `ix` and `lst` that tells me if `ix` makes sense as an index of `lst`, i.e. that `lst[ix]` makes sense.

I already know you can do something like

```r
is.index <- function(ix,lst){
  ans = FALSE
  try({ans=all(!is.na(lst[ix]))},silent = TRUE)
  return(ans)
}
```

But I want it to work when the list contains `NA`s, and when it's `lst` is a list it works differently. Both of these cases I could probably easily take care of as special cases, but I feel that I don't know all the possible ways to index, and all the intricacies of these, so I have no way of knowing if I have nailed all the special cases.

I know the "make sense" term isn't well defined, but it would seem reasonable to me, that there exist a function or at least a somewhat easy way of telling if an index is reasonable.

So is there a function or a simple way to do that, preferable not something requiring a try or a try catch statement?

**EDIT:** I realize that I haven't been clear in the statement of my question. Even if `ix` is a vector I want to know if `lst[ix]` makes sense, and not a vector telling me if `lst[ix[i]]` makes sense for the different possible values of `i`. Preferably we should have that no matter the type of `ix` and `lst` the function should always be able to return *one* logical value i.e. a `TRUE` or a `FALSE`. For example if `lst = 1:5` and `ix = c(-1,2)` should return `FALSE` and not `c(TRUE,TRUE)`.

Further clarification: Personally I don't like the partial matching or that it makes sense to index by non-integer doubles (I like even less that it just uses the integer part (rather that e.g. rounding to closest integer (useful for small precision errors) or taking the floor (makes `lst[x/y] = lst[x%/%y]`))); but since it makes sense to R I think it should be up to the preferences of the answerer whether to return `TRUE` or `FALSE` in these situations. The same goes for `lst[0]` and `lst[NA]`, whereas since `list("Cheese" = 4)["Che"]` gives `NA` I don't think that partial matching should be accepted.

But seeing that (at least I think) requiring the answerer to make their own choices is bad practice; if I were to choose I think that all these (except partial matching) should be accepted and returned as `TRUE`.

Comment: As you say, "make sense" term isn't well defined. That is the crux of the problem. What should `idx=0`, or `idx=NA` or `idx=1.2` do? What about partial matching? What about `is.index(1:3, idx=4)` or `is.index(1:3, idx=1:4)` or `is.index(1, idx=-(F:T))`? Once you define what the expected behaviour is for all the edge cases, you've basically written the function you want.

Comment: @dww : I realize that you are probably correct! I just have a naive hope that you are incorrect! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following seems to do the job. It uses partial matching to match character `ix` with the vector or list names.

```
is.index <- function(X, ix){
  if(is.character(ix)){
    if(is.null(names(X))) FALSE
    !is.na(pmatch(ix, names(X)))
  }else{
    abs(ix) <= length(X)
  }
}
```

Test with vectors.

```
x <- 1:6
y <- setNames(x, letters[x])
is.index(x, 2)
is.index(x, 7)
is.index(x, -3)
is.index(y, 'a')
is.index(y, 'z')
```

And now with lists.

```
lst <- list(1:6, letters[1:4])
is.index(lst, 3)
is.index(lst, "a")
is.index(lst, -1)
```

But there are problems, partial matching only works with the `$` extractor function, it doesn't work with `[[`, not even with `[`.

```
lst2 <- setNames(lst, c("A", "2nd"))
is.index(lst2, "A")

is.index(lst2, "2n")
lst2$`2n`              # works
lst[['2n']]            # fails
```